# width: 100% не корректно работает

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Сайт https://dwimarketing.ru шапка имеет position: fixed; и width: 100% и в мобильной версии она растягивается в ширину больше, чем ширина экрана, хотя body и html имеют ширину 100% и все работает корректно. Помогите, пожалуйста, очень срочно.

Comment: [mcve] должен быть прямо в тексте вопроса без ссылок

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего это происходит из-за анимированного показа элементов, т.к. изначально они располагаются за пределами контентной области и создают ту самую пустую область, на которую растягивается фиксированная шапка.
Оберни весь контент страницы в блок и задай ему overflow-x: hidden; должно помочь.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Выручил прям перед дедлайном)